# jQuery $.getJSON method giving CORS error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this code for getting data from another server. It worked for a long time without any problem.

```js
$.getJSON( "https://example.com/api", function( data ) {
  var array = [];
  
 $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
  array.push( JSON.stringify(val.SOMEVALUE) );
  });
```

But today I noticed that there were some problems. I see an error when I open the console as follows:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://example.com/api' from origin 'MYWEBSITEADDRESS' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I am a beginner and I am waiting for your help to solve the problem.

Comment: Something has changed with the website that they are now blocking your off site request.  You will want to reach out to the admins of the site and find out what they need do to remedy it, if they want to, or if there are now additional things they need to allow your request past their CORS restrictions.

Comment: Given that you are hitting a url that ends with `/api`, it may be as simple as them now requiring the inclusing of an api key now that you need to add.  But that's information they will need to give you.  Or they could have dorked up their CORS settings with the public api, and it's actually an unintended issue they've caused.

Comment: @Taplar Actually it is an example link and the end of the original link doesn't end this way. It is a public API. In addition, I see that the site is currently using CloudFlare. I think the problem is due to this reason.

Comment: In any case, if it was working and is now not working, you have to reach out to the people who maintain it for support.  There is no generic answer to all CORS issues, other than to tell you that the server you are trying to hit is denying requests from your off site page.  So the fix will involve something on their side, or you making a change to your request with new information that they now expect.  Both of those will involve communication with the destination website.  We can't answer those questions.

Comment: Otherwise, include in your question the actual api that you are trying to use and if anyone is familiar with it, or inclined to dig around about it, they may be able to tell you what you are missing.